# PrimeNG the fieldset css is not the same as the original of the website

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, fieldset

In my site the fieldset looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/TTS8s.jpg
I did not move in css that changed the fieldset

I use the primeNG v7 and Angular 7

```
<p-fieldset legend="Toggleable" [toggleable]="true">
    The story begins as Don Vito Corleone, the head of a New York Mafia family, oversees his daughter's wedding. 
    His beloved son Michael has just come home from the war, but does not intend to become part of his father's business. 
    Through Michael's life the nature of the family business becomes clear. The business of the family is just like the head of the family, 
    kind and benevolent to those who give respect, 
    but given to ruthless violence whenever anything stands against the good of the family.
</p-fieldset>
```

In the primeNG site the fieldset looks like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Fe1x.jpg ,I want this aspect.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Thanks

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap?

Answer (score 0):

Check your CSS of font for this primeng fieldset